# Typing Haskell in Haskell: Get all Assumps

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

I've been following along http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/TypingHaskellInHaskell.html and it has worked out great so far. The only problem is how to get all the computed `Assump`-Values out of the type-inferencer/type-checker (I've renamed all binds to be globally unique) because the final function

```
tiProgram :: ClassEnv -> [Assump] -> Program -> [Assump]
```

only returns `Assump`s for the top level `BindGroup`s. I've tried to change the Let-Binding Expression inference (branch in `tiExpr`) to something like

```
do (ps, as') <- tiBindGroup ce as bg
   (qs, t) <- tiExpr ce (as' ++ as) localExpr
   s <- gets t_subst
   rs <- reduce ce (apply s ps')
   s' <- defaultSubst ce [] rs
   let assumps = apply (s'@@s) as'
   storeAssumps assumps
   return (ps', t)
```

but this will not work for obvious reasons (unresolvable ambiguities).